# PHP form - image upload

Tags: php, html

My request today is to give the possibility to the users of my site to upload an image and to modify this image to add elements in PHP.

> index.php

```
...
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="photo" name="photo" lang="fr">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="photo">Choose an image...</label>
    </div>
...
```

> result.php

```
$photo = $_POST["photo"];
```

I would like, with the image file sent by the users, to do this kind of thing (i.e. "paste" this upload image on a source image already known by the server (written directly in the code of the site)) : https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/918836-concevez-votre-site-web-avec-php-et-mysql/916429-creez-des-images-en-php

Any ideas ?

For the moment, when I choose an image in my files and I click on "open", nothing is displayed in the file selection bar, as if nothing had happened... I use Bootstrap...

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: you need to use `$_FILES['photo']` rather than `$_POST['photo']` - what does `do this kind of thing` mean? Are you hoping that we will read through that entire page you linked to and understand from that what you actually wish to do with the uploaded image?

Comment: My goal is quite simple, take the image sent by the user, "paste" it in the right place on a source image and output to the user the modified image (source image + image sent by the user).

Comment: OK - please add all the code that you have written so far to solve this problem

Comment: Many things are simple to say that aren't simple to code.

Answer (score 0):

> index.php

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="resultatcasier.php" method="post">
<h3>Informations sur le suspect</h3>
<hr>
    <p>Photo du suspect</p>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" lang="fr">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">Choisir une image...</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Prénom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputPassword4">NOM (en majuscule)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Sexe:</p>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">Homme</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">Femme</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

> resultatcasier.php

```
$photo = $_POST["photo"];
$nom = $_POST["nom"];
$prenom = $_POST["prenom"];
$sexe = $_POST["sexe"];
print '$nom';
print '$prenom';
print '$sexe';
```

Comment: I don't get any error messages, I just don't know how to make a user upload an image, and call that image later in my PHP code.

Comment: So what you basically want to happen is for someone to finish your program?

Comment: No, I'm asking if anyone can unblock me or if anyone knows a doc about it.

Comment: There are already many solved threads in SO for your issue of uploading an image via HTML and PHP. As to the rest of your design goals, you should take a stab at it then post back here if you run into problems.